# How can I deinit my UITableViewCell instances when I refresh the table?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I refresh my table, I'd like all the previous cells to deinit (but it's not happening).  I'm pretty sure I don't have any references holding on to it.

This is my refresh method:

```
apiClient.listUsersNow(start, num: num, filter: filter) {  [weak self] (response) -> Void in
        if self != nil && response != nil && response["status"] == "success"{
            self!.items = [] //data source
            self!.tableView.reloadData()
            for(_, stuff): (String, JSON) in response["data"]["results"]{
                if let user_id = stuff["id"].int {
                    self!.items.append(user_id)
                }
            }
            self!.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        callback()
    }
```

I'm under the impression that when I call `reloadData()`, the old cells should deinit by themselves and that I'm **not** required to do it manually.

Apparently I'm wrong...must I loop through each cell and call `cleanupCell()` before reloading the data ?

Comment: Why do you need to deinit them? Are you trying to remove them completely from the table?

Comment: Reloading the table should not deinit the cells, the table still keeps the cells in its reuse pool and will reuse them next time you dequeue a cell with the same identifier.

Comment: If you need to cleanup a cell before it us reused, override the `prepareForReuse` function of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything, the cells are allocated/deallocated as they are needed by the tableview cell. The tableview maintains a collection of cells and reuse them as needed. All you need to do is use `dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier` in the tableview datasource method `cellforrowatindexpath`. Alternatively you can create them manually but they are deallocated automatically by ARC if you do not hold a `strong` reference to them.